# mp4parser TrimVideoUtils.java creates videos with incorrect media properties

Tags: java, android, video

I implemented the code for mp4parser TrimVideoUtils.java from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/android-4.2.2_r1/src/com/android/gallery3d/app/TrimVideoUtils.java in my app and everything works like it is supposed to. In my case the code trims down an mp4 video clip to a smaller size. However, the new file ends up with corrupted media properties and won't play in a VideoView (I get the error "Can't play this video").

The file plays fine with any other video player on the android device outside of the app, it just won't play inside of a VideoView in an activity. So I inspected the trimmed video properties using Windows Explorer and I can see that the following properties are incorrect:

Duration says 00:00:00

Width says 0

Height says 0

My question is: How do you manually set the media properties with Java on an existing video, or how do I prevent the mp4parser from stripping away essential properties during the trimming process?

Comment: I decided to use ffmpeg4android instead of mp4parser. It is a much better library, BUT the same thing happens! No duration, width, height, sample rate, frame rate. Everything gets stripped and the videos become unplayable inside of a VideoView. In desperate need of a solution here...

Comment: I use MediaMuxer for trimming video and it works fine for me. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/634248d/src/com/android/gallery3d/app/VideoUtils.java